# I am getting 100% accuracy in my decision tree model. Where I was wrong?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

```
#split dataset in features and target variable
feature_cols = ['RIAGENDR_0', 'RIDAGEYR', 'RIDRETH3_2', 'RIDRETH3_3', 'RIDRETH3_4', 'RIDRETH3_6', 'RIDRETH3_7', 'INDFMPIR', 'DMDMARTZ_1.0', 'DMDMARTZ_2.0', 'DMDMARTZ_3.0', 'DMDMARTZ_4.0', 'DMDMARTZ_6.0', 'DMDEDUC2', 'RFXT010', 'BMXWT', 'BMXBMI', 'URXUMA', 'LBDHDD', 'LBXFER', 'LBXGH', 'LBXBPB', 'LBXBCD', 'LBXBSE', 'LBXBMN', 'URXUBA', 'URXUCD', 'URXUCO', 'URXUCS', 'URXUMO', 'URXUMN', 'URXUPB', 'URXUSB', 'URXUSN', 'URXUTL', 'URXUTU']
X = data[feature_cols] # Features

scale = StandardScaler()
X = scale.fit_transform(X)

y = data['depre_score'] # Target variable


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) # 70% training and 30% test


clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print(y_test)
print(y_pred)

confusion = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(confusion)

print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

recall_sensitivity = metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=1)
recall_specificity = metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=0)
print(recall_sensitivity, recall_specificity)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you think you are doing something wrong? Perhaps your data are such that you can achieve a perfect classification... e.g., see this [mushroom classification](https://www.kaggle.com/code/ahmedelsaied3210/mushroom-classification-100-accuracy).

Having said that, it is also possible that there is some leakage in your data as specified by @gtomer. That means an exact point that is present in training set is available in your test set. You can do [K-fold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) test on your data and see how it follows up with the accuracy. And secondly, use different classifiers too (it is better to *use Random Forests* compared to Decision Trees)